# How to pass record id to a lightning component when it is opened as subtab

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, workspaceapi

I want to pass `recordId` on click of a button which opens a lightning component as subtab. Here is the code I tried, but no luck though `recordId` attribute is there in sub-tab documentation.

**Controller:**

```
openTabWithSubtab : function(component, event, helper) {
    var workspaceAPI = component.find("workspace");
    workspaceAPI.openTab({
        url: '/lightning/r/Account/001xx000003DI05AAG/view',
        focus: true
    }).then(function(response) {
        workspaceAPI.openSubtab({
            parentTabId: response,
            recordId: component.get("v.recordId")
            url: '/lightning/cmp/c_MyComponentLightning',
            focus: true
        });
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
}
```

**Component:**

```
<aura:component implements = "lightning:isUrlAddressable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,force:hasRecordId,flexipage:availableForRecordHome" access = "GLOBAL">
  <aura:attribute name = "recordId" type = "String"/>
  <lightning:workspaceAPI aura:id="workspace" />
  <lightning:button onclick = "{!c.openTabWithSubtab}" label = "openSubTab" />
</aura:component>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Explanation on why its not working:

```
workspaceAPI.openTab({
    url: '/lightning/r/Account/001xx000003DI05AAG/view',
    focus: true
})
```

You need to use `url: '/0010K000026Y6QZQA0'` for giving url. `/lightning/r` should not be there. But the problem here is after you give record id in this way, it fetch the record but then realize that you are in lightning experiance and fetches lightning UI for you. You can observe the URL changes at run time.

On the other hand, when you use `recordId`, the console tab or subTab will open that particular record in its lightning record page.

```
recordId: component.get("v.recordId")
url: '/lightning/cmp/c_MyComponentLightning'
```

This is NOT valid. When you give recordId, you are telling subTab to open that particular record and so it will simply ignore the url.

I understood that you want to open your custom component and pass attribute values in it. You should be using pageReference for that scenario.

Here is how you need to do:

```
openTabWithSubtab : function(component, event, helper) {
    var workspaceAPI = component.find("workspace");
    workspaceAPI.openTab({
        recordId: 'a0r0K000063jMXKQA2',
        focus: false
    }).then(function(pTabId) {
        workspaceAPI.openSubtab({
            parentTabId: pTabId,
            pageReference: {
                type: "standard__component",
                attributes: {
                    componentName: "c__MyComponentLightning"
                },
                state: {
                    c__recordId: "XXXXXXXXX23QW"
                }
            },
            focus: true
        });
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
}
```

> For the lightning experience types that the page reference object supports, it is recommended to use pageReference ONLY and not use direct URL. You can find pageReference types [HERE](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_navigation_page_definitions.htm)

Comment: thanks a lot !!! It saved my time. When I'm trying to retrieve recordId in "MyComponentLightning" by using "component.get("v.recordId")", it's always undefined. May I know why? How to retrieve the same?

Comment: You should get it from state (from page reference)

Comment: Thank you so much !! clear cut explanation that was !!!!